# How to search int key from doubly linkedlist?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

The key is the input from user.
I am trying to compare the int key with the string id to see if they are equal.
if string id == int key. then just return this link.
otherwise, I want to compare all the ids in the list.

```
1. Add a student to records
2. Remove a student from records
3. Search a student from records
4. Display all students in records
5. Quit
```

when I input 3 students, its only compare the first one and the last one. 
How can I fix it? thanks for your help:)

```
public Link searchStudent(int key)
{ 
    Link temp = new Link(null,null);
    temp = cursor;
    int idNumber=0;

    if(size>=key){
        System.out.println("Ready to Search...");       
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

            System.out.println("key--->"+key);
            System.out.println("id--->"+temp.getId());

            idNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp.getId());
            if(idNumber==key)
                System.out.println("You found it!");
            else
                temp = cursor.next;
        }

    }
    return temp;        
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more of your code. There are references in your `searchStudent` method to fields that are obviously initialized outside of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't change your `temp` or `cursor` variable inside the loop. I can only guess what `cursor` means in your class, but if you treat it as head of the list, then you need to change `temp` on every iteration.  Also, when you found element with `id` that equals to `key` I guess you want to stop search. See the code below.

```
public Link searchStudent(int key) { 
    Link temp = cursor;
    int idNumber = 0;

    if(size >= key) {
        System.out.println("Ready to Search...");       
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            System.out.println("key -> " + key);
            System.out.println(" id -> " + temp.getId());

            idNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp.getId());
            if(idNumber == key) {
                System.out.println("You found it!");
                break;
            } else {
                // Here!
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }

    }
    return temp;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match String to an int

```
        if(temp.getId().equals(key+""))
            System.out.println("You found it!");
```

or this

```
  String sKey=key+"";   
  if(skey.equals(temp.getId())
       System.out.println("You found it!");
```